# Unity.Android I want encrypt assets/bin/data in the apk file. But not find resource

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I packaged bin/data into a encrypted zip file
then
In Application.attachBaseContext(), I release the resource to /data/data/xxxxx/file/res.zip
then
Add the resource to the AssetManager, but unity prompts that the resource cannot be found
Then I noticed
In unity, Application.dataPath =/data/APP/xxxxx/base. Apk/
I think unity may directly read base.apk to load resources. As long as I can modify the value of base.apk, I can modify the load path.
so
I hook LoadedApk and modify Applicationinfo.sourceDir and Applicationinfo.publicSourceDir to/data/data/xxxxx/file/res.zip, but not find too
How does unity read the path to base.apk?